# Недоступно [должно быть] доступное свойство класса. Что не так?

Tags: c#

Собственно, фрагмент кода (.NET 4.7.2; VS 2019 Preview 5.0):

```
    public class CommonFilter
    {
        private CommonFilter next;
        public CommonFilter Next { get { return next; } set { next = value; } }
        public CommonFilter GetNext() => next;

    }

    public class FiltersListEnum<CommonFilter> : IEnumerator<CommonFilter>
    {
        private CommonFilter current;
        public CommonFilter Current => current;
        object IEnumerator.Current => this.Current;
        public bool EndOfList => (Current?.Next == null); 
    }
```

При определении метода чтения для свойства EndOfList, при обращении к .Next возникает ошибка компиляции

*CS1061 "CommonFilter" не содержит определения "Next", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Next", принимающий тип "CommonFilter" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).*

Все определения - public. Замена Current?.Next на this.Current?.Next ожидаемо не помогло. Функция GetNext() тоже недоступна. Всю голову сломал - что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы назвали параметр типа точно также, как и класс здесь

```
FiltersListEnum<CommonFilter>
```

Уберите его, он вам вообще тут не нужен.

```
public class FiltersListEnum : IEnumerator<CommonFilter>
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!

Comment: @Dimanson пожалуйста